# Trying to bring predictions back to respective row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, keras

I am making predictions from my model in the form of a numpy ndarray. They are all correct with sigmoid output. I'd now like to plug back in every value in the numpy array back into the dataframe to its corresponding row as well as have a conditional saying if > .5 then == 1 else < .5 == 0

So far I can read the numpy array but I can't seem to add it to the dataframe correctly one by one

```py
employers = data_churn
# employers = np.array([employers])
predictions = model_churn.predict(employers)
predictions

employerPredictions = real_churn
employerPredictions = employerPredictions.rename(index=str, columns={"main_reason": "churned"})
employerPredictions.drop(['biztype_knowledge','biztype_field','biztype_creative','PercentEmpChg','PercentChgRevenue','PercentChgPay','amountOfResignations','nb_months_active'], axis=1, inplace=True)
if predictions.any() > .5:
    employerPredictions['predictedChurn'] = 1
    employerPredictions['ConfidenceWillChurn %'] = round((predictions[0][0] * 100), 2)
else:
    employerPredictions['predictedChurn'] = 0
    employerPredictions['ConfidenceWillNotChurn %'] = round(((1 - predictions[0][0]) * 100), 2)


employerPredictions
```

So far the any method just returns the first prediction and sets it for all in the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to round predictions to 1s and 0s:

```
employerPredictions['predictedChurn'] = np.round(predictions).astype(np.int8)

#Or you just downcast it to int
employerPredictions['predictedChurn'] = predictions.astype(np.int8)

#Or use np.where
employerPredictions['predictedChurn'] = np.where(predictions>=0.5,1,0)
```

As far as the ConfidenceWillChurn % or ConfidenceWillNotChurn % I would try like this, but I'm not sure this is what you're asking.

```
employerPredictions['ConfidenceWillChurn %'] = np.where(predictions>=0.5,predictions*100,np.nan)

employerPredictions['ConfidenceWillNotChurn %'] = np.where(predictions<0.5,(1-predictions)*100,np.nan)
```

I put np.nan but you can chose another value for when the condition is not satisfied.
I used the [where-method from numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Pandas has a where-method as well, but does something different.

Comment: This is great but how would I add the condition of the % Confidence? Because if the sigmoid is > .5 then this works but those that are < .5 show a low % rate. For those I want to specifically do 1-predictions * 100

Comment: I added something and tidied up my answer. Let's see if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Almost. This is giving me two columns with NaNs but I just want them both in one column. But I can just concat both columns together now. Thanks!